# How to call function instead of screen inside Drawer on React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I Used `"react-navigation": "^4.0.10", "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.2",`

and implement a drawer and inside them, I added my item, one of them is **"Call us"** and it should open a phone so I used for it **Linking** and I don't know if that's a good way to invoke a function instead of Screen as default in RN-drawer

so I do that's **But after click to this item my app crashed and stop to work!!** so how can I achieve this?

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
 ...
 CallUsDrawer: {
      screen: () => Linking.openURL(`tel:0597093830`),
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'call us',
        drawerIcon: () => <Icon name="ios-call" size={28} color="#1E558E" />,
      },
    },
 ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach. You should create a `contentcomponent` for the `createDrawerNavigator` and there should be a `<Button>` or something for "call us". and in `onPress` of that component wright the logic  `Linking.openURL(`tel:0597093830`)`

plese check,

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-contentcomponent

Sample

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
   ... screens here
  },
  {
    contentComponent: MenuScreen,
    drawerWidth: 300
  }
);
```

where `MenuScreen` is a Componet

Answer (score 0):

Use `DrawerItem` instead of `Drawer.Screen`. [Complete Docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/). Example available in this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fcustom-drawer-content.js)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).